# FileNotFoundError with catalogs

Tags: python

My catalog tree:

```
.
├── BotAdmin
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── media
│   │   │   ├── post_media
│   │   │   └── products_images
|   |   |       └──default.jpg
├── Components
|   ├── base
|   |   └── main.py
│   ├── catalog
│   │   └── v1
│   │       └── catalog.py
└── venv
```

when I try to get image in `catalog.py` when executing main.py:

```
image = open('../../../BotAdmin/static/media/products_images/default.jpg', 'rb')
```

I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: The relative path needs to be relative to your ***cwd (current working directory)***, not to where the python file is located

Answer (score 1):

It depends from where you run Python.
If you run it in `.`, the path should be `./BotAdmin/static/media/products_images/default.jpg`.